# What's the difference between time.time() and pygame.time.get_ticks()

Tags: python, time, pygame

**time.time()**

> Return the time in *seconds* since the epoch as a floating point number. On Windows and most Unix systems, the *epoch is January 1, 1970, 00:00:00* (UTC) and leap seconds are not counted towards the time in seconds since the epoch." [Python.org #time.time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time)

**pygame.time.get_ticks()**

> "Return the number of *milliseconds* since *pygame.init() was called*. Before pygame is initialized this will always be 0." [Pygame.org #pygame.time.get_ticks](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks)

How I often use them:

```
# for time.time()
start = time.time()
elapsed_time = time.time() - start

# for pygame.time.get_ticks()
start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
elapsed_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() - start
```

In terms of usage, I don't see any difference between them. What other features do they have that the others doesn't have?

Comment: It's not really about their differences, they are basically the same, but they come from *different packages*, which have *different modules*

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for this:

```
start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
elapsed_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() - start
```

Simply the following as it relies on how long since `pygame.init` was ran:

```
__init__ ...
elapsed_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

But here `time.time()` has more *other* usages in the same module that are similar to this (recording time), pygame has fewer. Otherwise yes they are exactly the same, maybe some slight differences in runtime etc.

`time.time_ns() → int`

> Similar to time() but returns time as an integer number of nanoseconds since the epoch.

`time.thread_time() → float`

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of the sum of the system and user CPU time of the current thread. It does not include time elapsed during sleep. It is thread-specific by definition. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of two calls in the same thread is valid.
>
> Use thread_time_ns() to avoid the precision loss caused by the float type.

`time.thread_time_ns() → int`

> Similar to thread_time() but return time as nanoseconds.

`pygame.time` has more sub modules than this, but they are more for pygame usage than in general usage.

Comment: What I really meant by ```elapsed_time``` is the time from ```start``` and not from pygame init. Like how you'd use them for cooldown systems where skills were cast not from pygame init but at some point in the code.

Answer (score 1):

`time.time()` returns the time in **seconds** since the epoch. [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) returns the time in **milliseconds** sine `pygame.init()` was called.

---

**You can also use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) to get the elapsed time between 2 frames**. [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) returns the number of milliseconds since the last call.

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    elapsed_time = clock.tick()                # milliseconds
    elapsed_time_seconds = elapsed_time / 1000 # seconds
```

Note, the method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. So you can limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage and get the accurate elapsed time at once:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 100
run = True
while run:
    elapsed_time = clock.tick(FPS)
```